# Asp.Net MVC 4 Regular Express Attribute does not show message of mine

Tags: asp.net

I am working over an application in Asp.net MVC4.0 where i am Model CountryInformation 
having the following attributes.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Country Name")]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[+-]?[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?$",ErrorMessage = "Input decimal numbers.")]
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    //[RegularExpression(@"^[+-]?[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?$", ErrorMessage = "Input decimal numbers.")]
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    //[RegularExpression(@"^[+-]?[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?$", ErrorMessage = "Input decimal numbers.")]
    [Display(Name = "GMT Offset")]
    public float GMTOffSet { get; set; }

    public string Currency { get; set; }
```

Everything is working fine when the model is validated after i input the wrong value for Latitude field i.e. abc not a decimal of course then It doesn't show my Error Message but "
The value 'abc' is not valid for Latitude." every in the page source i have seen the value for

```
<input id="Latitude" class="input-validation-error text-box single-line" type="text" value="abc" name="Latitude" data-val-required="This field is required." data-val-regex-pattern="^[+-]?[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?$" data-val-regex="Input decimal numbers." data-val-number="The field Latitude must be a number." data-val="true">
```

The value 'abc' is not valid for Latitude.
Please describe that why I am not seeing my message

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you were in a room and it is your job to make sure that blocks inserted through a hole in the wall were round.  To achieve this value, the hole is made round.  Your job, when you get a square block, is to sound the alarm, which is 3 bells.

Now, someone comes along and attempts to place a square block through the round hole.  Ooops... It doesn't fit.  So you never get the square block and can't sound the alarm.  Instead, the person sounds an alarm of 2 bells because he can't fit the square block in the round hole.

In this comparison, the regular expression is you.  You are told to validate something that cannot possibly happen, because abc cannot be stored in a decimal value.  Therefore, the value of Latitude or Longitude can never NOT be a valid decimal value (particularly since you did not use a nullable decimal, therefore it's default value is always 0.0 and cannot be null).

Meanwhile, the MVC framework notices that you're trying to stuff a character string into a decimal value, which it can't do.. so it throws a generic error.

In other words, using decimal automatically validates that it's a valid decimal number.  If you use a nullable decimal, then it validates it's a decimal number or null.  You can then use the Required validator to ensure it's not null and pass your own message.

If you want to use the regular expression validator, you will have to make Lattitude and Longitude strings, and then convert them to decimals later in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
*^[0-9]([.,][0-9]{1,3})?$*
```

it will accept

x.y and x,y type data if you did't want , replace expression with

```
*^[0-9]([.][0-9]{1,3})?$*
```

The problem is with the `?:` in you expression it checks but not capture.

Comment: your suggest regex doesn't my need because I have this 
latitude=15 or 15.15 or +15 or -20.5
same goes for Longitude and GMT Offset.
If Its the regex that's causing another message to be displayed and kindly suggest me a regex that suits my need.
Thank You

Comment: So your problem is + and - sign before the decimal values
No problem just add [+-]? before the regular expression
Now the new expression is
*^[+-]?[0-9]([.][0-9]{1,3})?$*